# How to click on the element with text as "Phone to call with" within <md-select> dropdown through Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I am trying to automate an application which has a  type drop down.
I have tried all possible combinations like below but have not been able to select an element from drop down list.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@aria-label=\"Phone to call with\"]"));
```

I am not able to find xpath by ID as it keeps changing with reload.

[image]

Below is the html code. How would i achieve the same?

```
<md-select ng-model="ctrl.selectedLinkedPhone" class="ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" aria-multiselectable="false" id="select_26" aria-invalid="false" aria-label="
        Phone to call with
      " style=""><md-select-value class="md-select-value md-select-placeholder" id="select_value_label_25"><span>
        Phone to call with
      </span><span class="md-select-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span></md-select-value><div class="md-select-menu-container" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" id="select_container_27"><md-select-menu role="presentation" class="_md"><md-content class="_md">
        <!----><md-option ng-disabled="!ctrl.isLinkedPhoneCurrentlyVerified(linkedPhone)" ng-repeat="linkedPhone in ctrl.getLinkedPhones()" ng-value="linkedPhone" tabindex="0" class="md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_29" aria-checked="true" aria-disabled="false" value="[object Object]" style=""><div class="md-text">
          Phone 1
        </div></md-option><!----><md-option ng-disabled="!ctrl.isLinkedPhoneCurrentlyVerified(linkedPhone)" ng-repeat="linkedPhone in ctrl.getLinkedPhones()" ng-value="linkedPhone" tabindex="0" class="md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_30" aria-checked="true" aria-disabled="false" value="[object Object]" style=""><div class="md-text">
          Phone 2
        </div></md-option><!----><md-option ng-disabled="!ctrl.isLinkedPhoneCurrentlyVerified(linkedPhone)" ng-repeat="linkedPhone in ctrl.getLinkedPhones()" ng-value="linkedPhone" tabindex="0" class="md-ink-ripple" role="option" aria-selected="false" id="select_option_31" aria-checked="true" aria-disabled="false" value="[object Object]" style=""><div class="md-text">
          Hangouts
        </div></md-option><!---->
      </md-content></md-select-menu></div></md-select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This xpath works for your html:

```
By.xpath("//md-select[normalize-space(@aria-label='Phone to call with')]")
```

or you can use ccs selector:

```
By.cssSelector("md-select[aria-label*='Phone to call with']")
```

To find option, for example with text "Hangouts" you can use:

```
By.xpath("//md-select[normalize-space(@aria-label='Phone to call with')]//md-option[normalize-space(.)='Hangouts']")
```

To select dropdown you can use Action class or 2 methods below, implement waits needed: 
1. let think that you don't have special button to open dropdown and click on the dropdown will open it. 
2. using javascript:

```
WebElement selectMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//md-select[normalize-space(@aria-label='Phone to call with')]"));
WebElement option = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//md-select[normalize-space(@aria-label='Phone to call with')]//md-option[normalize-space(.)='Hangouts']"));

//1. first click to open dropdown, second click on option
selectMenu.click();
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(option)).click();

//2. select using javascript
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", option);
```

Comment: Thanks!! The click on selectMenu does not work with this approach, hence it gives an error saying element option is not found. It is a pop-up window which gets activated on clicking call button in Google Voice. I tried switching to using window handlers but I see only one 1 window present.

Comment: Share html after click on selectMenu

Comment: I made a few modifications like below and now i am able to see the drop down and it highlights the new option but does not select it. I have updated the screenshot in question.
    WebElement option = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//md-option[normalize-space(.)='Phone 2']"));
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", option);

Comment: First put wait to be clickable see @Debanjan answer, then use simple click - option.click(), if not try option.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER). Check my updated answer, I added wait

Answer (score 0):

Try using this below xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@aria-label,Phone to call with']"));
```

Comment: Thanks!! I had tried this it dose not work. I am not able to locate the element.

Comment: @manjulamanju Please don't post multiple (identical) answers for the same question. Instead publish a single well researched answer. Feel free to edit it as if required and delete the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

If that drop-down is developed by div tag then we have to automate that by using Action Class methods.If possible you can send that page Url I will send solution.

Comment: Thanks Manjula!!! It is google voice application to place a call. On clicking call but it asks to select either mobile number or hangouts via a drop down on this child window.

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **Phone to call with** you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//md-select[@class='ng-pristine ng-valid ng-empty ng-touched']/md-select-value[@class='md-select-value md-select-placeholder' and starts-with(@id,'select_value_label_')]//span[contains(.,'Phone to call with')]"))).click();
```